# PHPDkim - getting dkim=hardfail in Gmail

Tags: php, email, dkim, spf

I'm trying to authenticate my outgoing mails using SPF and DKIM.

I have configured SPF and DKIM entries for the domain imhadoop.com.

I'm using PHPDkim library to send emails.

I see the following in Gmail:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.35.73 with SMTP id f9csp37326iej;
    Sun, 10 Feb 2013 19:27:12 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.68.244.35 with SMTP id xd3mr15213610pbc.28.1360553232375;
    Sun, 10 Feb 2013 19:27:12 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <xxx@imhadoop.com>
Received: from sg2nlvphout02.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net    (sg2nlvphout02.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net. [182.50.132.196])
    by mx.google.com with SMTP id d10si39427959paz.321.2013.02.10.19.27.11;
    Sun, 10 Feb 2013 19:27:12 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxx@imhadoop.com designates 182.50.132.196 as  permitted sender) client-ip=182.50.132.196;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxx@imhadoop.com designates 182.50.132.196 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=xxx@imhadoop.com;
   dkim=hardfail header.i=@imhadoop.com
Received: (qmail 7920 invoked from network); 11 Feb 2013 00:26:47 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO ip-182-50-154-44.ip.secureserver.net) (182.50.154.44)
by sg2nlvphout02.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net (182.50.132.196) with ESMTP; 11 Feb   2013 00:26:47 -0000
Received: by ip-182-50-154-44.ip.secureserver.net (Postfix, from userid 0)
id C69847DEE38; Sun, 10 Feb 2013 20:27:10 -0700 (MST)
To: xxx@gmail.com
Subject: test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 500:dkim-test.php
X-DKIM: php-dkim.sourceforge.net
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; l=2; s=imhadoop;
t=1360553230; c=relaxed/simple;
h=From:To:Subject;
d=imhadoop.com;
z=From:=20"Fresh=20DKIM=20Manager"=20<xxx@imhadoop.com>
|To:=20xxx@gmail.com
|Subject:=20test;
bh=uoq1oCgLlTqpdDX/iUbLy7J1Wic=;
b=Ps2QRGG74dT8WCpDUS5qliXzHM9mpWze7qhdeOML39oB1puFUXNnFHuAUpy6MSSYAzTYRxKUKCYRyGc8T obL9rP6iLzaGbq507aF7s5W00ayq3HQjHJ+oNPGPZxsEqob/jg4+6meaBm2Dc2nGaJWAymdS5nICOmg1k5QvOlx6P8=
From: "Fresh DKIM Manager" <xxx@imhadoop.com>
To: xxx@gmail.com
Reply-To: xxx@imhadoop.com
Content-Type: text/html
MIME-Version: 1.0
Message-Id: <20130211032710.C69847DEE38@ip-182-50-154-44.ip.secureserver.net>
Date: Sun, 10 Feb 2013 20:27:10 -0700 (MST)
```

Though the mail passes SPF check, Gmail says DKIM hardfail.

Comment: Have you tried a [DKIM validator](http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/)? Some report the specific problem they've encountered.

Comment: I sent an email to autorespond+dkim@dk.elandsys.com and got a response that DKIM passed